# Unity crash upon opening a specific scene

Tags: unity, scene

I have this one specific scene that I spent over 20 hours building. But as of today when I attempt to open it unity crashes. I have opened the error log and it states:

```
Unity.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module Unity.exe at 0033:4150123b.

Error occurred at 2017-09-22_200636.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe, run by MarcR.
62% memory in use.
16257 MB physical memory [6165 MB free].
32641 MB paging file [18590 MB free].
134217728 MB user address space [134213224 MB free].
Read from location 00000098 caused an access violation.
```

I have tried running the program as administrator, updating the unity editor and cleaning the cache.

The funny thing is that I am actually able to open the scene additive to my current scene.

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

(On an end note I did not want to post ALL of the error log if you need to see please comment and I will, of course, link it)

Comment: Surely you have it in source control so you can revert to an earlier state?

Comment: I can make a few suggestions. Make a back up of your project before you do this. Try finding your project's folder that was created in your 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow' and delete it. Then reopen your project.

Comment: If that doesn't help, there is an official Windows system tool you can download called procmon (process monitor) that gives you very detailed info on what a process is reading and writing, including if it has an issue with an access violation on your system with a specific file in your project.